# How do I remove variables from the variable table when my module uninstalls?

Tags: 6

I'm working on a Drupal 6 module that adds some variables to the variable table. How can I go about having those variables removed from the variable table when the module is uninstalled?

Comment: **UPDATE:** On further digging through the [discussion on this blog post](http://zzolo.org/thoughts/tip-managing-variables-drupal-module), I ran across this idea from Dave Reid to [adopt the method that Drupal core uses](http://zzolo.org/thoughts/tip-managing-variables-drupal-module#comment-73).

Comment: This will delete variables for other modules like "examplemodule_extreme", too.

Comment: @Mark Trapp: Yeah, there's some discussion of that in the comments on the post. I've updated my answer with a link to to a better idea in that discussion.

Comment: @Matt I'd still be leery about using a new, generic hook like that for fear of namespace collision, but that's definitely a better alternative. And to be clear, the method Dave Reid uses (implementing `hook_variables()`) is *not* how core does it: that's how he does it in some of his own modules. In Drupal 8, this problem might be solved with the [addition of a core `hook_variable_info()` hook](http://drupal.org/node/145164).

Comment: @Mark Trapp: Yeah, I made the assumption that core did it that way based on the subject of Mark's reply. I did some digging though and was surprised to find that quite a few core modules still don't yet implement hook_uninstall at all.

Comment: Well, some core modules might not have any variables and some are required and can't be uninstalled like node and user. So it's pointless for these to implement hook_uninstall(). That said, it's perfectly possible that some variables aren't correctly uninstalled even in core. It's something that is easily forgotten. I invested *many* hours myself trying to get hook_variable_info() into core but that is simply not going to happen with the current variable system, it makes it too complex and too slow.

Comment: Thanks - I'll go with Dave Reid's suggestion. My module dynamically generates variables based on the content types and languages that are running on the Drupal site it's installed on, but as the variable names are constructed sensibly it's pretty easy to reconstruct them from the node_type and languages tables.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Keep track of your variables and add appropriate [`variable_del()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/variable_del/) calls within an implementation of [`hook_uninstall()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--install.php/function/hook_uninstall/6):

```
function foo_uninstall() {
  variable_del('foo_variable1');
  variable_del('foo_variable2');
}
```

As `hook_uninstall()` is an installation hook, it needs to reside in your module's `.install` file (e.g. `foo.install`).

You ought not to delete *all* variables prefixed with your module's name as namespace collisions will come back to bite you. For example, if your module's name is `foo`, you might think you should just poll the `variables` table for all variables prefixed `foo_`. But what if I write a module named `foo_awesome`? You'd delete my variables, too. That wouldn't be nice.